# CSS doesn't respond and also the Images don't load

Tags: html, css

The `main.css` is located in a folder named `css`, and the `index.html` is outside the folder.

```
<head>
    <title>Tornike's Page</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "css/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

My Code
[image: My Code]

The Website and developer tools
[image: The Website and developer tools]

Comment: make sure `main.css` in `css` directory or try adding slash `"/css/main.css`

Comment: Arrange like this may be it will help `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
`<link href = "css/main.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" >` check  and css path is it right ?

Comment: I did those things, nothing helped, Yes I think that css path is right, I mean look at picture and tell me if its wrong . Weirdest thing is that this code worked about a week ago, and today I wanted to continue and finish the work but this happened ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have folder structure. If you really have it and does not works then you can try `./css/main.css`. Otherwise I'd tried to go with `main.css`.

Comment: Nope , didn't work, I dont really understand what do you mean by folder structure, can you be any more specific ?

Comment: I mean: do you see this structure in explorer too not only in your editor?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it guys, Just needed to edit my path so it would say : "Website/css/main.css" , Thanks for answers.